# Encoding Error with Topo To Raster

Tags: python, encoding, arcpy

I'm relativley new to python and I already found a ton of questions and answers about encoding and the UnicodeEncodeError, but I can't figure it out for my specific problem and keep getting this error: "*UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xf8' in position 7: ordinal not in range(128)*". I am using IDLE Python 2.7.12

I want to use the arcGis tool TopoToRaster for a set of ca. 200 lakes. I have one folder containing 200 folders(one for each lake), in each lake-folder there are three shapefiles with names lakename_P.shp for points, lakename_B.shp for polygon/boundary and lakename_L.shp for polyline. The lakes are danish lakes and therefore almost all contain ø, æ and/or å in the folder names and shp names.

I am iterating through the single folders with a for loop and run the tool for every lake taking the right feature classes as an input.

I found this code, which actually works with my code, but I can't print anything with it and i am also aware of the disatvantages so I want to avoid it.

```
import sys
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf8')
```

other solutions used the .encoding when reading and writing files, which I don't really do.

Can anyone recomend a solution other than reload(sys). Maybe I just have to put the .encoding somewhere, but I really don't know where and how to. I am thankfull for every help but want to mention that I already read all the Python Unicode HOWTO and other blog posts.

```
-*- coding: iso-8859-15 -*-
import arcpy
from arcpy import env
from arcpy.sa import *
path = "//projects/soer"
arcpy.env.workspace = path
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

# Check out the ArcGIS Spatial Analyst extension license
arcpy.CheckOutExtension("Spatial")

wss = arcpy.ListWorkspaces("*", "Folder")
wss.sort()

for ws in wss:
   arcpy.env.workspace = ws
   for polygon in arcpy.ListFeatureClasses(feature_type = "Polygon"):
       myBoundary = polygon
   for point in arcpy.ListFeatureClasses(feature_type = "Point"):
       myPoint = point
   for polyline in arcpy.ListFeatureClasses(feature_type = "Polyline"):
       myContour = polyline

   output = ws + '/' + 'ttr'
   outTTR = TopoToRaster([TopoPointElevation([[myPoint, 'z']]), 
                          TopoContour([[myContour, 'z']]),
                          TopoBoundary([myBoundary])], 2, 
                          "#", "#", "#", "#", "NO_ENFORCE")
   outTTR.save(output)
```

Comment: Have you successfully run the TopoToRaster tool within ArcMap on this data? That is typically my first step in troubleshooting such problems -- if the ArcMap tool is the source of the encoding conflict, then you won't be able to circumvent that conflict within ArcPy. (You could hypothetically rename or copy your source data to not use the "problem" characters, but I'd still confirm whether the source ArcMap code is where your encoding issue is.)

Comment: @Erica yes I run it within ArcMap and it worked without troubles, but I now solved it actually :) But thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I finally managed to solve it myself and it was as easy as that:

```
for polygon in arcpy.ListFeatureClasses(feature_type = "Polygon"):
    myBoundary = polygon.encode('utf-8')
for point in arcpy.ListFeatureClasses(feature_type = "Point"):
    myPoint = point.encode('utf-8')
for polyline in arcpy.ListFeatureClasses(feature_type = "Polyline"):
    myContour = polyline.encode('utf-8')
```